# Remove leading Zero from file names with Powershell

Tags: powershell, leading-zero

Good morning.

I am having trouble understanding past topics. I am a new user with minimal understanding.

My file path that I would like to remove all leading zeros from the file names in it is this.

CD Documents\Attachments

Basically what I want to do is copy paste that file path into Powershell then copy paste a command to remove all leading zeroes from the file names in that folder.

and example of the file name would be 0123456789xxxxxxxxxx (length and characters vary)

I would like 123456789xxxxxx

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look at the `.TrimStart()` method that each file `.BaseName` will have.

Comment: I looked into that but could not get it to work. These are the errors I got trying it various ways.

Comment: PS C:\Users\awiget\Documents\Attachments> TrimStart()
At line:1 char:11
+ TrimStart()
+           ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression

Comment: PS C:\Users\awiget\Documents\Attachments> TrimStart(0)
TrimStart : The term 'TrimStart' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ TrimStart(0)
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TrimStart:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: i see that `Mathias R. Jessen`  got it working for you. kool! [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Lee_Dailey comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67126958/remove-leading-zero-from-file-names-with-powershell#comment118653299_67126958), you can use the [`TrimStart()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=net-5.0) to trim leading characters off a string:

```
# Change location to the folder
cd Documents\Attachments

# Discover all the files in the current folder with leading 0s in their name
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Filter 0*

# Use `Rename-Item` with `TrimStart` to rename the files to the appropriate name without the leading 0s
$files |Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.TrimStart('0') }
```

Comment: Now I may be kicking a gift horse in the mouth but I got to ask. I have to rename hundreds of files daily. I am wondering if there is a faster method using wild card characters. I get files named all sorts of things. But the constant is that there is always a string of numbers in front sometimes with a leading zero sometimes not but they always have 9-10 digits. Is it possible in addition to the removing the leading zero to rename the end of the file? Like this. 0123456789 xyzpdq whatever to this? 123456789_LM MOD CLOSING PKG. I am currently using a number of rename commands to accomplish this

Comment: @user1987966 "I need something faster" sounds like an _imagined_ problem :) have you actually tried to measure how fast/slow this is against a 100 files?

Comment: When I say hundreds I mean in the range of 300 to 500 files each day. While using various string commands is not entirely painful it still takes time. Was just curious about the possibility and wildcards have always fascinated and confused me.

Comment: @user1987966 Again, test/benchmark if you have a concern :) On my laptop, discovering and renaming 1000 files with leading zeros in a folder with ~3000 files takes less than 1 second (~850ms). Regarding your second question: [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide all necessary details :)